# What do I need to run Qt apps on Debian?

Tags: debian, qt

I am trying to run an application which uses Qt on a Debian 7 server and I get the error message: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
and when I run it with -platform offscreen: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "offscreen".

I have tried following various fixes for ubuntu and Windows which didn't work for me, couldn't find any for Debian.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What fixes did you find for Ubuntu? Perhaps we can adapt them for Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you install Qt via `apt-get install libqt4-gui`, the library `libxcb.so` gets pulled as a dependency. Try to run this command (again?), and if `apt-get` complains about any anomalies, try to fix them with `apt-get -f install`. Hopefully it will sort things out.